# How can I rearrange the columns/fields in linq select clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data object which contains a list of customers.

Here is the Customer class:

```
public class Customer{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Specialization {get; set;}
    public DateTime? JoinedAt {get; set;}
}
```

When I run the following query it will generate the last based on the customer model.

```
var Customers = data.Select(x => new Customer { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, Specialization = x.Specialization, JoinedAt = x.JoinedAt }).ToList();
```

I want to rearrange the fields placements dynamically like this order
`Name, Id, JoinedAt, Specialization`
or
`Specialization, Name, Id, JoinedAt`.

How can I select dynamically like the order mentioned above?

Comment: You can assign properties in any order `new Customer{ Name = x.Name, Id = .Id }`. But it looks like you're trying to create copy - you can use `MemberwiseClone` to copy all fields of object

Comment: There is no order for properties of object inside a `List`. You order them when using them when ooutputing or storing to database, e.g. `1. Console.Write(Name), 2. Console.Write(Id) ...` or `INSERT INTO table (Name, Id, ..) VALUES(@Name, @Id)`.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NetMage I am trying to rearrange the columns dynamically. Like if I enter `Specialization, Name, Id, JoinedAt` from the frontend input field. The output from the query should be like this.

By default, it will return based on the customer model. So can I rearrange the fields ?

Comment: "rearrange the columns" has no meaning when talking about data objects and classes. They don't have columns. What columns do you mean?

Comment: @NetMage Okay, so how can I show the data based on the entered sequence like  `Specialization, Name, Id, JoinedAt`?

Comment: What framework are you using to display the data to the user? If using one with data binding then each field is bound to a property and you just change the order (in the UI) of the display fields to change the apparent order of the data.

Comment: @ChrisBD the end output is an excel sheet. So, how can I put the input order `Specialization, Name, Id, JoinedAt` in the excel sheet?

Comment: @Abdul Rauf, provide a code example, which you use to fill Excel sheet. At least, part where you fill cells.

Comment: @Auditive,  I am using google sheet API. 
`AppendDataList AppendDataList = new AppendDataList();
AppendDataList.values = **Data**;
var sheetName = GoogleUserDetail.SheetName + "!A1:I";
var SheetNameWithRange = Uri.EscapeDataString(sheetName);
request.AddJsonBody(AppendDataList);
                        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + GoogleUserDetail.Token.ToString());
                        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);`

Comment: @Abdul Rauf, as I can understand, you appending whole data at once as table. For your purpose to order in way you want, I think, you need to write data row by row, setting values to cells in a row in order you need.

Comment: @Auditive, if I start to implement row by row then it will take too much time based on bulky data.

Comment: @Abdul Rauf, can suggest reorder Google Sheet directly by dragging columns instead of filling row by row :D As in **ChrisBD**'s answer for common Excel sheet, that's the only way to achieve what you want.

Comment: What is `AppendDataList`? Where did it come from?

Answer (score 0):

If your output is the current OpenXML Excel format then the following is an example of C# code. Please note that its untested - just adapted from some code of mine.

Using DocumentFormat.OpenXML package by Microsoft.
Note that data is only committed when a `Save` command is called.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Class to encompass the OpenXML SDK interaction
    /// </summary>
    public static class ExcelAccessor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Given a column name, a row index, and a WorksheetPart, inserts a cell into the worksheet. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnName">Name (text) of column</param>
        /// <param name="rowIndex">Row number</param>
        /// <param name="worksheetPart">Worksheet in which to insert Cell</param>
        /// <returns>Cell if already exists</returns>
        public static Cell InsertCellInWorksheet(string columnName, uint rowIndex, WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
        {
            var worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
            var sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            var cellReference = columnName + rowIndex;

            // If the worksheet does not contain a row with the specified row index, insert one.
            Row row;
            if (sheetData.Elements<Row>().Count(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex) != 0)
            {
                row = sheetData.Elements<Row>().First(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };
                sheetData.Append(row);
            }

            // If there is not a cell with the specified column name, insert one.  
            if (row.Elements<Cell>().Any(c => c.CellReference.Value == columnName + rowIndex))
            {
                return row.Elements<Cell>().First(c => c.CellReference.Value == cellReference);
            }

            // Cells must be in sequential order according to CellReference. Determine where to insert the new cell.
            Cell refCell = null;
            foreach (var cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                if (cell.CellReference.Value.Length != cellReference.Length) continue;
                    
                if (string.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, cellReference,
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) <= 0) continue;
                refCell = cell;
                break;
            }

            var newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellReference };
            row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell);

            worksheet.Save();
            return newCell;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts a new worksheet within a workbook
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="workbookPart">WorkBookPart to insert a new worksheet into</param>
        /// <param name="sheetTitle">Title to apply to the worksheet</param>
        /// <returns>New WorkSheetPart created</returns>
        public static WorksheetPart InsertWorksheet(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string sheetTitle)
        {
            // Add a new worksheet part to the workbook.
            var newWorksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
            newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

            var sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
            var relationshipId = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart);

            // Get a unique ID for the new sheet.
            uint sheetId = 1;
            if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Any())
            {
                sheetId = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
            }

            var sheetName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sheetTitle)?$"Sheet {sheetId}":sheetTitle;

            // Append the new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
            var sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = sheetName };
            sheets.Append(sheet);
            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

            return newWorksheetPart;
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be used in a manner something like this:

```
//Create spreadsheet
var spreadsheet =  SpreadsheetDocument.Create("Spreadsheet1.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
var workbookPart = spreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();
workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
var worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

var sheets = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

//Create headings
uint row = 1;
worksheetPart = ExcelAccessor.InsertWorksheet(spreadsheet.WorkbookPart, "Customers");
var cell = ExcelAccessor.InsertCellInWorksheet("A", row, worksheetPart);
cell.CellValue = new CellValue("Specialization");
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);

cell = ExcelAccessor.InsertCellInWorksheet("B", row, worksheetPart);
cell.CellValue = new CellValue("Name");
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);

cell = ExcelAccessor.InsertCellInWorksheet("C", row, worksheetPart);
cell.CellValue = new CellValue("Id");
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);

cell = ExcelAccessor.InsertCellInWorksheet("D", row, worksheetPart);
cell.CellValue = new CellValue("JoinedAt");
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);

row++; //ensure that data entry occurs in row below headings

//Assuming that you have a list of customers 
List<Customer> customers = GetSomeCustomerDataFunction();

//Enter data into spreadsheet       
foreach(var customer in customers)
{
    cell = ExcelAccessor.InsertCellInWorksheet("A", row, worksheetPart);
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(customer.Specialization);
    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);

    cell = ExcelAccessor.InsertCellInWorksheet("B", row, worksheetPart);
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(customer.Name);
    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);

    cell = ExcelAccessor.InsertCellInWorksheet("C", row, worksheetPart);
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(customer.Id);
    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);

    cell = ExcelAccessor.InsertCellInWorksheet("D", row, worksheetPart);
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(customer.JoinedAt); //Not sure if a conversion required here
    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Date);

    row++
}   
worksheetPart.WorkSheet.Save();
workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
spreadsheet.Close();
```