# How can I rearrange list indexing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am working on google spreadsheets, user connect its spreadsheet, and the system pushed data to user connected spreadsheet at day end.
here are spreadsheet columns
The sequence of columns is
`"PatientName","DOB","StripeId","Card","ChargeCreated","Status","Amount"`

here is the code is used

```
 var GoogleSpreadSheetData = db.GoogleSpreadSheetDatas
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new List<string>{
        x.PatientName.Trim(),
        x.DOB.Trim(),
        x.StripeId.Trim(),
        x.Card.Trim(),
        x.ChargeCreated.Trim(),
        x.Status.Trim(),
        x.Amount.Trim(),
     })
    .ToList();
```

the sequence of google spread sheet columns and query return is same sequence like
`"PatientName","DOB","StripeId","Card","ChargeCreated","Status","Amount"`
and data will mapped on exact column in spread sheet [Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UeBs.png).

if user changes sequence of columns like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwkvH.png), replaced `PatientName` column to `DOB`. when next time data push to spreadsheet `PatientName` data is pushed in the `DOB` column and vice versa.

Before pushing data to the spreadsheet, firstly I call google API(using Developer Metadata) to get a sequence of that spreadsheet, I got the updated column sequence in response.

`My question is`

How can I change the sequence on query select?
Can I rearrange the list on query select or after?

Please help to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: We already talking about it at now here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69930298/how-can-i-rearrange-the-columns-fields-in-linq-select-clause?noredirect=1#comment123617891_69930298

Comment: Your question needs details, which API method do you use? How you prepare data for API?

Comment: I don't think you should need your first `ToList()` in your database query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your MetaData query provides you with a `List<string>` of column names:

```
List<string> spreadsheetColSeq;
```

Then you can query the database to retrieve the rows:

```
var dbData = db.GoogleSpreadSheetDatas
   .Select(x => new List<string> {
        x.PatientName.Trim(),
        x.DOB.Trim(),
        x.StripeId.Trim(),
        x.Card.Trim(),
        x.ChargeCreated.Trim(),
        x.Status.Trim(),
        x.Amount.Trim(),
    })
   .ToList();
```

And then you can create a mapping from the query order to the spreadsheet order and reorder the each row's `List<string>` to match the new order:

```
var origSeq = new[] { "PatientName", "DOB", "StripeId", "Card", "ChargeCreated", "Status", "Amount" };

var colOrder = spreadsheetColSeq
    .Select(colName => Array.IndexOf(origSeq, colName))
    .ToList();

var GoogleSpreadSheetData = dbData
    .Select(row => colOrder.Select(idx => row[idx]).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Note: If columns may be deleted, this will crash since `Array.IndexOf` will return `-1` for a missing value. You could filter `colOrder` by adding `.Where(idx => idx > -1)` before the `ToList()` to skip missing columns.